# How to assign values to an Object in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a RestApi which sends me the response in a Json Format which has for example  a address object which then holds the address1, address2, city etc. So i created an interface in my app which holds the definition of these objects like

```
export interface ISurveyResponseDetail {
  docID?: string;
  permission?: string;
  property?: IProperty;
  surveyID?: string;
}
export interface IProperty {
  address1?: string;
  address2?: string;
  city?: string;
  state?: string;
  zip?: string;
```

then in my ts file i want to use a data adapter to map my response into this interface. But i am not sure how i would the property Object of type IProperty and then be able to assign the values

```
static adaptSurveyResponseDetail(data): ISurveyResponseDetail {
        if (data) {
            return {
                property:
                // address1 _.get(data, 'property.address1', null),
                // city _.get(data, 'property.city', null),
                docID: _.get(data, 'docID', null),
                permission: _.get(data, 'permission', null),
                surveyID: _.get(data, 'survey_id', null),
              };
            } else {
            return data;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
static adaptSurveyResponseDetail(data): ISurveyResponseDetail {
    if (data) {
      return {
        property: {
          address1: data.address1,
          address2: data.address2,
          city: data.city,
          state: data.state,
          zip: data.zip,
        },
        docID: data.docID,
        permission: data.permission,
        surveyID: data['survey_id'],
      };
    } else {
      return data;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thats not the issue i am having. Whats my problem is that my Interface ISurveyResponseDetail has an property object of type IProperty which in turn has then the address1 etc. I am having an issue assigning values to address1 as it does not directly exist in the ISurveyResponseDetail

Answer (score 1):

> I have a RestApi which sends me the response in a Json Format

I think maybe you are making this more complex than it needs to be? [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) has generic methods that allow you to cast the parsed json response to an interface.

```
getSurveyResponse() : Observable<ISurveyResponseDetail> {
  return httpClient.get<ISurveyResponseDetail>('/end/point/here');
}
```

Comment: In my Case the API returns additional info depending on the Endpoint. Which means it first would be a API Response and then in the Data Part it would be depending on the endpoint a <ISurveyResponseDetail> or <ISurveyResponseDetail[]>

Comment: @NoSoup4you - Ideally you should be writing at least 1 service call per end point which means that my above example would be extended with an additional method like `getSurveyResponses(): Observable<ISurveyResponseDetail[] { ....` (notice the plural form in the method name).

Comment: I get the general idea but how would i do that when the type i could observer is the APIResponse and then lets say i would want the ISurveyResponseDetail which will be in the Data element of the API response

Comment: @NoSoup4you - either `httpClient.get<{data: ISurveyResponseDetail}>('end/point')` or you can use `pipe` with `map` to return the `data` property directly: `httpClient.get<{data: ISurveyResponseDetail}>('end/point').pipe(map((result) => result.data))`

Answer (score 1):

Don't make all of the properties of your interface optional. You can define an extra type to be partial, and only use that in cases where the flexibility is needed.

```js
export interface ISurveyResponseDetail {
  property: IProperty;
  docID: string;
  permission: string;
  property: IProperty;
  surveyID: string;
}

export type ISurveyResponseDetailPartial = Partial<ISurveyResponseDetail>;

export interface IProperty {
  address1: string;
  address2: string;
  city: string;
  state: string;
  zip: string;
}

export type IPropertyPartial = Partial<IProperty >;
```

Don't use *underscore* to set default values as `null`. Define a default object instead.

```js
const DEFAULT_SURVEY_RESPONSE_DETAIL: ISurveyResponseDetail = {
  property: DEFAULT_PROPERTY,
  docID: null,
  permission: null,
  property: null,
  surveyID: null
}

const DEFAULT_PROPERTY: IProperty{
  address1: null,
  address2: null,
  city: null,
  state: null,
  zip: null
}
```

You don't need an adapter to rebuild the object, because the HTTP client can deserialize JSON into a type for you. If you want to have *missing* properties set as `null`, then constructor a new object using the default object as the first parameter and then apply the values. Any missing properties will remain set as `null`.

```js
getSurveyResponseDetail() : Observable<ISurveyResponseDetail> {
  return this.http.get<ISurveyResponseDetail>(...).pipe(
     map(data => {
        const property = {...DEFAULT_PROPERTY, ...(data.property || {})};
        return {...DEFAULT_SURVEY_RESPONSE_DETAIL, ...data, property};
     });
}
```